# Can you use global variables inside a t4 template?

Tags: t4

How can I use global variables in a TT file?

If I declare a variable in the header I get a compile error if I reference it in a function.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<# 
     int ValueForThisFile = 35;

     SomeFunction();
#>

<#+
void SomeFunction() {
#>
    public void GeneratedCode() { 
        int value = <#=ValueForThisFile#>;
    }
<#+
}
#>
```

I know that I could pass it as an argument but there are hundreds of calls and it would be syntactically tighter if I could avoid that. If this were one file I could hard code the value but there are dozens of files that have different settings and common include files that generate the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.  When T4 parses your template it is actually generating a class.  All the <# #> contents are injected into a single method on that class while all <#+ #> tags are added as methods to that class, allowing you to call them from the single method <# #> tags.  So the scope of the "ValueForThisFile" variable is limited to that single method.  For a simple example, this template:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<# 
     int ValueForThisFile = 35;

     SomeFunction();
#>

<#+
void SomeFunction() {
   return ValueForThisFile;
}
#>
```

Would Generate a class like this:

```
class T4Gen {

private void MainWork() {
    int ValueForThisFile = 35;
    this.SomeFunction();
}

private void SomeFunction{
    return ValueForThisFile;
}

}
```

The variable "ValueForThisFile" is only scoped to the MainWork function.  The actual class T4 generates is much more complicated but as you see there would be no way to have a global variable in code like that.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I had noticed that it was a class because I noticed that I could call other functions but didn't have the big picture as to the structure.

Comment: If you want to see the class that is generated you can set the debug attribute to true on the template tag, it will save the generated file.  Here are the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586945.aspx) from MS explaining it.  Look at the section on debug attribute, it talks about how the intermediate code file is written to the %Temp% directory.

Comment: So after looking at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126545.aspx) some more it states that <#+ #> (Class Feature Blocks) tags can contain methods, fields, and properties.  In theory, code you place in those blocks will be injected into the body of the class so you might be able to place a "private int ValueForThisFile;" statement in a <#+ #> and be able to set if from the <# #> and still be able to access it from the body of methods defined in other <#+ #> blocks

Answer (score 1):

Structuring your T4 script like this might help, I have been using similar approaches in my projects successfully: -

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#     
    var Context = new ScriptContext();
    Context.SomeFunction();
#>
// This file is generated by Build/Info.tt, do not modify!
void SomeFunction() {
    public void GeneratedCode() { 
        int value = <#=Context.ValueForThisFile#>;
    }
}

<#+
public class ScriptContext {
    public int ValueForThisFile = 35;

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        ValueForThisFile = 42;
    }
}
#>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to share variable accross functions in T4 template, Try this,

```
<#@ template  debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#
    InitGlobalVariable();
    AddNames();
    ShowNames();

#>

<#+
    //T4 Shared variables
    List<string> names;
#>

<#+

private void InitGlobalVariable()
{
    names = new List<string>();
}

private void AddNames()
{
    names.Add("Mickey");
    names.Add("Arthur");
}

private void ShowNames()
{
    foreach(var name in names)
    {
#>
        <#= name #>
<#+  
    }
}
#>
```

Declare your variable inside <#+ ... #> and then initialize inside  <# ... #>